# Styling a Select element from react-select

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-select

I'm using a select element from the react-select library, and in my project I'm using styled-components.
I wanted to ask if it is possible for me to style it in my styles.ts file. if it's not possible, can you guys give any suggestions of how to do the styling??

Inside a React:FC

```
import Select from 'react-select'

...

const options = [
    { value: 'Income', label: 'Income' },
    { value: 'Expense', label: 'Expense' },
  ]

...

       <Form>
        <InputElement />
        <Select options={options} />
      </Form>
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible to provide your own custom styles, `react-select` provides an object-based approach for styling the `Select` component.

Reference to the [docs](https://react-select.com/styles#styles)

Here is a simple example,

```js
const customStyles = {
  option: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    borderBottom: '1px dotted pink',
    color: state.isSelected ? 'red' : 'blue',
    padding: 20,
  }),
  control: () => ({
    // none of react-select's styles are passed to <Control />
    width: 200,
  }),
  singleValue: (provided, state) => {
    const opacity = state.isDisabled ? 0.5 : 1;
    const transition = 'opacity 300ms';

    return { ...provided, opacity, transition };
  }
}

const App = () => (
    <Select
      styles={customStyles} // pass the customStyles object to the styles prop
      options={...}
    />
);
```

Select is very customizable through the keys provided to the custom [style object](https://react-select.com/styles#style-object).

One thing to remember is that each key will be a style function where the first argument will be the provided styles and the second argument will the state of select i.e `isFocused`, `isSelected`.

**EDIT**- While it is the suggested way of providing custom styles with the object-based approach. If you really want to style the `Select` component with `styled-components`, here is an example (you have to provide a `classNamePrefix` through prop and style based on classNames)

More on details on styling with classNames [docs](https://react-select.com/styles#using-classnames)

```js
import Select from 'react-select';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const SelectElement = styled(Select)`
  .react-select-container {
    // custom styles
  }

  .react-select__control {
    // custom styles
  }

  .react-select__indicators {
    // custom styles
  }
`;

const MySelect = (props) => {
  return (
     <SelectElement classNamePrefix="react-select" options={options} {...props}/>
  )
}
```

Comment: OP specified they wanted to use styled-components

Comment: Yes, I understand, but unfortunately, select consists of multiple individual components and suggested way of styling through the object-based approach. Unless you want to go `className` hunting.

Comment: You cannot just do `ReactSelectStyled = styled(ReactSelect)` and expect everything to work. See the [docs](https://react-select.com/styles#style-object)

Comment: I am not arguing if your approach is better or not, I am only saying that's not what OP asked, and yes you can do `ReactSelectStyled = styled(ReactSelect)` and expect everything to work if you know the classNames, cheers!

Comment: @ludwiguer there you go, updated the answer of styling with `styled-components`

Comment: @subashMahapatra How to initialize and pass the `provided` object.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it like this

```
import ReactSelect from 'react-select';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const ReactSelectStyled = styled(ReactSelect)`
   // you have to provide custom styles through class names
   // example
   .react-select__option {
      // custom styles
   }
`;
```

Additionally, you can change the prefix of the class name (i.e "react-select" part in the class names) by providing the prefix through the `classNamePrefix` prop to the `Select` component.

Comment: With this approach you have to go `className` hunting and modify the styles for the `className`. `react-select` provides the API for custom styling. See the [docs](https://react-select.com/styles#styles)

Comment: OP asked if it could be done using styled-components, the answer is yes and this is the approach, even if you need to go className hunting

Comment: Please update your answer with a little more details on custom styles with class names, because it is absolutely necessary to achieve the desired result when styling the `Select` component with `styled-components`.

Comment: I have edited with some details, you can do another edit if it doesn't look go to you.